# How to convert from image to text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tesseract.js

I am trying to convert image to text. When anyone upload image then press "Submit" image text should be show into the textarea. My following code is not working, please help!

**Code:**

```
 <html>
    <body>
    
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">  
    <br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<br><br>
    
    <label><b>Your Converted Text:</b></label><br><br>
    
    <textarea cols="30" name="original" rows="10" style="width: 100%;" id="convertedText">
    </textarea>

    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
    
    <script>  
     function myFunction() {
           var myImage= document.getElementById('myFile');
          
    
           Tesseract.recognize(myImage).then(function(result){
    
            console.log(result.text);
    
           document.getElementById("convertedText").value = result.text;
            
    
            });
    }
            </script>
            
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to pass an actual image to the recognize method, not just the reference to some file upload field. https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/image-format.md

Comment: Show the image as a text in the textarea or as image?

Comment: @Edson Magombe I want to show the text from the image in TextArea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach an event listener to the file input, you can then recognize text once the file has been loaded successfully, like so:

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">  
<br><br>

<label><b>Your Converted Text:</b></label><br><br>

<textarea cols="30" name="original" rows="10" style="width: 100%;" id="convertedText">
</textarea>

<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>

<script>  

    var myFile = document.getElementById('myFile');
    myFile.addEventListener('change', recognizeText);

    async function recognizeText({ target: { files }  }) {
        Tesseract.recognize(files[0]).then(function(result) {
            console.log("recognizeText: result.text:", result.text);
            document.getElementById("convertedText").value = result.text;
        });
    }

</script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but still image text is not showing in textArea. Their is some random text is coming with your code!

Comment: Ok, cool. Thank you very much for trying my answer! Have you tried a very basic example, like a Hello World image?

Comment: Hello world image is properly getting converted and result is showing Hello World. but some other images are not properly converting

Comment: It looks like some fonts are unrecognized to the tool! Is their any way by which we make it recognize most image text?

Comment: Ok, great, so you can train Tesseract to recognize different fonts. You can also try upsampling the images, this can improve recognition. We might also try changing the language. Tesseract have an example of custom training here: https://github.com/jeromewu/tesseract.js-custom-traineddata/blob/master/browser/index.html